# Symfony3 Monolog Settings for email and file logging

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-2.8, php-7.1, monolog

I work on two different projects based on symfony2.x and symfony 3.x.
I want to setup both projects to send me an email for critical errors, but just log error-level errors.

The following setting works on symfony 2.8 but not on symfony3.

```yaml
monolog:
handlers:
    main_critical:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        excluded_404:
            - ^/
        handler:      grouped_critical
    grouped_critical:
        type:    group
        members: [streamed_critical, buffered_critical]
    streamed_critical:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_critical.log"
        level: critical
    buffered_critical:
        type:    buffer
        handler: swift_critical
    swift_critical:
        type:       swift_mailer
        from_email: "%error_mail_sender%"
        to_email:   "%critical_error_mail_recipients%"
        subject:    Critical error occurred!
        level:      critical
    main_error:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      grouped_error
    grouped_error:
        type:    group
        members: [streamed_error]
    streamed_error:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%log_file_path%"
        level: error
```

The error is :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /var/www/statistic/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php on line 7

I am not sure what's wrong with this setting as it works for symfony 2.8 but not 3.x.

But when I remove this following block, then it works on symfony 3 project. But it will log only critical errors via email without following settings.

```yaml
main_error:
    type:         fingers_crossed
    action_level: error
    handler:      grouped_error
grouped_error:
    type:    group
    members: [streamed_error]
streamed_error:
    type:  stream
    path:  "%log_file_path%"
    level: error
```

Any idea?

Comment: For general purposes, you should configure separate `dev` and `prod` environment debug settings. The `dev` settings should be expected to utilize XDebug and other debugging utilities, such as PHPUnit. Where the `prod` environment should not enable XDebug or include PHPUnit, as they are extra overhead that is not needed in a production environment. See [Will enabling XDebug on a production server make PHP slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522356/1144627)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of xdebug, please try to add into you php.ini or into you php configuration file this:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```