# How to capture and log infinite recursion errors in production PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, infinite-recursion

Recently I had a problem where because of invalid data in DB some PHP script ran into an infinite recursion on production. We have Sentry added in our system for error log management, but that did not help as there was no error thrown about - PHP just died, with no logs in Sentry or server file logs. It was pretty hard to pinpoint the root cause of the problem when it happened.

After doing some research the only thing I managed to find was that setting `xdebug.max_nesting_level` would throw an "Nesting too deep" error. How safe would it be to use this specific xdebug feature in production, if everything else is disabled? Or is there another alternative for catching recursion errors in production?

Comment: This sounds more like a case of trying to reproduce the error in a test environment.  Is it something which you could copy the database and reproduce the same scenario or is this unknown what causes it.  If you have logs of the requests being made, this may indicate what users were doing at the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch the fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861033/how-to-catch-the-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-p)

Comment: You should not have turned the error log on, otherwise you should be able to see a "Maximum execution time" or "Allowed memory size" log.

Comment: @shingo "maximum execution time" and "stack overflow" are different errors.

Comment: @Olivier php doesn't have a stackoverflow exception. it should be an "Allowed memory size ..." error, but the catch method is the same.

Comment: @shingo already tried to add a custom fatal handler but with no success, without xDebug enabled the script dies without entering the handler.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, that is how I resolved the issue when it arose, but it took quite some time. I was specifically wondering if this kind of error could be logged more user-friendly and hopefully resolved quicker without making data duplications on the test environment. xDebug nesting level limit seems to work for this issue, but I am a bit concerned about the security and performance side of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522182/will-enabling-xdebug-on-a-production-server-make-php-slower may give some information

Comment: A custom fatal handler? Didn't you click the link? It's about the shutdown function.